# Image url not displaying my uploaded images when django project loaded onto heroku site

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My uploaded images are not loading when uploaded to heroku and I think its not related to static file issue. When i set debug = False they come fine and i know that when it is false django uses itself to host the static assests. So setting that and my images loads fine but that's not the case if i set Debug = True on heroku or on my local env. Can somebody help me solve this issue.

template

```
<img class="img-fluid" style="height:auto;" src="{{post.work_img.url}}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
```

model

```
class WorkExp(models.Model):
    work_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="work_images/")
```

app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       path("carrer/", WorkExpView, name="carrer_page"),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
     path("", include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: `when it is false django uses itself`, no, vice versa. Which means Django config is not fine and probably `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` has wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

In project/urls.py  try this

```
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

instead of

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and set the debug = True

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `static_root` and are using `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."